# Parsing Simple Json Return in Twilio Studio / Liquid

Tags: json, twilio, liquid

I have a simple WIDGET in Twilio Studio which is a HTTP Widget.
It sends out a GET HTTP request to a PHP page.

The next widget is suppsoed to get the Data back which I am sending from PHP as Json and looks like

[“1-Document 1”,”2-Document “2,”Document “3]

When I access it from the next widget using {{widgets.getdocuments.body}} where "getdocuments" is the widget that sent out the HTTP request

1. I can't figure out how to split it properly, parse it and then have it display on new lines like

1 -Document 1
2- Document 2
3-Document 3

Any help is appreciated

I can get data in and out of twilio but can't seem to parse it properly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your HTTP request returns an array, which is unfortunately not supported:

> Note that, although an array is valid JSON, if your request returns an array of objects, it will not be parsed by your Studio Flow. Wrap the array within a JSON object to access array elements.

[Twilio Studio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request#returning-json)